# multidimensional array ouput not showing in java

Tags: java

```
class multable
{
   final static int rows =20;
   final static int colums =20;
    private static int coloums;
    private static int[][] product;
   public static void main(String[] args)               
   {
       int poduct[][]=new int[rows][colums];
       int row,coloum;
       System.out.println(" MULTIPLICATION TABLE");
       System.out.println("");
       int i,j;
       for (i=0;i<rows;i++)
       {
           for(j=0;j<coloums;j++)
           {
               product[i][j]=i*j;
               System.out.println(""+product[i][j]);
           }
           System.out.println("");

       }
   }
}
```

the SOP line inside the second for loop is not printing anything. even if we change what is inside it.

Comment: Remove `int row,coloum;` and I hope it will work.

Comment: Also, I believe since java 6(maybe 5?) you can pass an `int` into `System.out.println`. No need for the `""+` to get the implicit conversion.

Comment: @Cruncher It was always the case right from Java 1.0

Comment: @RohitJain Are you sure? I remember doing java 4 and having to do it. Maybe it was for something else

Comment: @Cruncher `println` is overloaded to take any primitive types. Here's [Java 1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) doc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 variables for *columns*, both spelled incorrectly unfortunately:

```
final static int colums =20;
private static int coloums;
```

2nd one being not initialized will keep it's default value `0`. And your inner loop is iterating using the 2nd variable.

Comment: also `int poduct[][]` probably should be `int product[][]`

Comment: And here was me thinking a good statically typed language avoided all this 'spelling things differently in different places' malarkey, ah well

Answer (score 0):

You define multiple variables that are not used (properly). There are plenty misspelled words in it..

change it e.g to this:

```
final static int rows = 20;
final static int colums = 20;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int product[][] = new int[rows][colums];
    System.out.println(" MULTIPLICATION TABLE");
    System.out.println("");
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < colums; j++) {
            product[i][j] = i * j;
            System.out.println("" + product[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println("");

    }
}
```